# Run command after resume

Tags: bash, scripts, systemd, ubuntu-mate

A previous post used info that is outdated for Ubuntu Mate 18.04.

According to this article, [Running scripts before and after suspend with systemd](https://blog.christophersmart.com/2016/05/11/running-scripts-before-and-after-suspend-with-systemd/), I have this script in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash 
#
# located in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/
# Created 4/2/19
exec 2> /tmp/systemd_suspend_test_err.txt
if [ "${1}" = "pre" ]; then
  # Do the thing you want before suspend here
  echo "we are suspending." > /tmp/systemd_suspend_test.txt
elif [ "${1}" = "post" ]; then
  # Do the thing you want after resume here
  echo "and we are back from being suspended" >> /tmp/systemd_suspend_test.txt
fi
```

However, none of the `echo` statements work.

Answer (score 4):

I feel kind of stupid, but I forgot to set the execute bit. Now the script works after I used:

```
chmod +x
```