# Play an notification sound to confirm sleep is triggered

Tags: suspend, 22.04

Because of this issue [Intermittent - Dell XPS 9310, 22.04 does not turn off with lid closed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407426/intermittent-dell-xps-9310-22-04-does-not-turn-off-with-lid-closed) (the lid switch doesn't trigger) I'd like to get feedback when sleep is initiated.

Is it possible to hook into the lid switch and play a notification sound when the lid is being closed and/or when sleep is triggered?

Edit: I've provided a partial answer below. However, the sound playback does not work. Is anybody else able to provide an answer including the sound playback?

Comment: For the sleep case, see this Q&A: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313479/correct-way-to-execute-a-script-on-resume-from-suspend  Short version: write a script in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jos and the answer by Tracy here: [Correct way to execute a script on resume from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313479/correct-way-to-execute-a-script-on-resume-from-suspend) I got part way. Then I found https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=246264.

Full solution: First make a note of your user name (say `sam`) and your user id:

```
id -u sam
```

Suppose your user id is `1000`. On Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, place a file with this content into `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` (using your user name `sam` and id `1000`):

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

case "$1" in
    pre)
    #code execution BEFORE sleeping/hibernating/suspending
    /usr/bin/sudo -u sam bash -c "export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000;  /usr/bin/ogg123 -q /usr/share/sounds/Yaru/stereo/desktop-logoff.oga"
    /usr/bin/date >> SOMEDIR/logs/sleep-monitor/pre.log
    ;;
    post)
    #code execution AFTER resuming
    # same code as above would work here.
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Check:

- Log and playback should work is called manually (`sudo script.sh pre`).
- The script should work when the system suspends, in that the log file `pre.log` is  updated as expected.  If that doesn't happen, check about the suspend service (see links above):

```
sudo systemctl status sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

Final note: Depending on your setup etc etc, it might take a bit for the laptop to actually suspend. So you'll only hear the sound once the laptop lid has been shut for a while.

Comment: Same unanswered question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140882/play-sound-when-suspending-and-resuming