# Laptop goes to sleep but wakes immediately

Tags: 22.04, xps

I've implemented this [Play an notification sound to confirm sleep is triggered](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407516/play-an-notification-sound-to-confirm-sleep-is-triggered) so that I've now got a sound for going to sleep and waking up. It turns out that sometimes, immediately after I close the lid, the laptop goes to sleep, but then wakes up again a few seconds later.

Dell XPS 13 9310 (16GB, touch screen), with Ubuntu 22.04.

(Edit 2022-05-28: The problem is intermittent - a reboot fixes it temporarily.)

Any ideas what might cause this or how I can diagnose it?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. It seems to not really sleep at all--selecting "sleep" from the menu will have the screen turn off for a second, and then turn right back on. Dell XPS 9710 (64GB, 4k touch), Ubuntu 22.04 Did you happen to install the latest nVidia driver? I tried some earlier kernels, and the problem seems to persist there (where it was working just days ago).

Comment: Hi Robert - thank you so much for the comment. I do not think I've installed the nVidia driver. Also, the problem is intermittent - a reboot fixes it temporarily.