# 2 finger scrolling stops working after suspend on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: suspend, touchpad

I am having a problem where 2 finger scrolling stops working after suspend. After a reboot it works fine again. I am running a Dell Inspiron 5515. I've gone through the forums where similar problems were discussed and tried the recommended fixes but nothing worked for me. I am new to Ubuntu and not very technical but I can follow instruction to paste commands into a terminal or edit files etc. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Does it start working again after logging out and back in without rebooting?

Comment: No it doesn't. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have found that after entering the following command in terminal the touchpad starts working again. "sudo modprobe -r hid-multitouch && sudo modprobe hid-multitouch" is there a way this can be automated?

Comment: The clean way to listen for system resume is to use https://askubuntu.com/a/1318782 . The sudo and the wantedby lines in your service example look weird. Probably you want to put the "modprobe -r" part at the suspend, and the "modprobe" part at the resume

Comment: The good news is it works. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a systemd service file:
   $ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/resume-commands.service
2. Add the following lines to the file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run custom commands on resume
After=suspend.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "sudo modprobe -r hid-multitouch && sudo modprobe hid-multitouch"

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

3. Save the file and close the editor.
4. Reload the systemd manager configuration:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

5. Enable the service to run on system startup:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable resume-commands.service
```

6. Reboot your system to apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file as 
`sudo vi /lib/systemd/system-sleep/tp-reset`

Add the following lines to the file

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "${1}" = "pre" ]; then
# Do the thing you want before suspend here
  echo "pre"
elif [ "${1}" = "post" ]; then
# Do the thing you want after resume here
  /usr/sbin/rmmod hid_multitouch && /usr/sbin/modprobe hid_multitouch
fi
```

Make it executable 
`sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/tp-reset`